# UITableView - get notification about scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview

Is there any way to know, when the UITableView scrolled ? I need something that is the same like scrollViewDidScroll in scrollview.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set your UITableView's delegate to `self`, the view controller should call `scrollViewDidScroll()` when the view is scrolled:

`myTableView.delegate = self`

This works because `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.